# Understanding xargs options -i and -t

Tags: linux, bash, shell, xargs

what is `-i` and `-t` in this this example

```
ls . | xargs -i -t cp ./{} $1
```

I understand that this is copying everything in the current directory into the argument that is passed in (`$1`) but I do not understand what `-i` and `-t` does.

> the example above is a snippet in a bash script file in case you are wondering of
>   the "argument.

Comment: This seems to be an error prone (breaks on filenames with blanks and target directory name with blanks / glob characters) and inefficient (runs `cp` for each file) way to do `cp ./* "$1"`.

Comment: Did you not try `man xargs` or did you run it but not understand what it said?

Comment: @EdMorton I didn't understand but i did try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`man xargs`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html):

> ```
>    -I replace-str
>           Replace occurrences of replace-str in the initial-arguments
>           with names read from standard input.  Also, unquoted blanks do
>           not terminate input items; instead the separator is the
>           newline character.  Implies -x and -L 1.
>
>    -i[replace-str], --replace[=replace-str]
>           This option is a synonym for -Ireplace-str if replace-str is
>           specified.  If the replace-str argument is missing, the effect
>           is the same as -I{}.  This option is deprecated; use -I
>           instead.
>
>    -t, --verbose
>           Print the command line on the standard error output before
>           executing it.
> ```

In your case, `-i` is being used without a replace-str after it, so think of it as `-I{}`. This means that the `{}` in `cp ./{} $1` gets replaced with each filename to copy.

Comment: i understand -t now... I still don't get -I

Comment: @edmamerto I added a bit of explanation for that.